# How far is Parse.com secured?

Tags: web-applications, parse-platform, data-security

I recently came across Parse.com where I developed an android app for storing the data in it. But right now I have to develop a web application using the same data I previously stored.

But my issue is that, parse is asking me to mention the 'app key' and 'java script key' in the  javascript file. and by the way I even have to mention the table names and column names in the same java script file. Which means I am giving the whole access of the data base to some random guy who is one click away from my data.

So how can I make it more secured ?

Comment: Thank You very much but the security and parse.com tags are not being allowed in http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the link below. These are client keys, the master key is the one you should be worried about.!

[SEE HERE](https://parse.com/questions/securing-application-id-and-api-key-in-javascript)

Comment: Also look at this [LINK](https://parse.com/questions/javascript-sdk-security)